# MarcEdit -import from mrc file to csv file

Tags: csv, tags, export-to-csv, bibliography, marc

I have just started working on MarcEdit, and I am having some trouble converting the mic file to CSV. I've looked into tutorials and followed every required step, but once I convert the file, all the tag field (as in the actual tags like 245, 500, 001, etc) are all put into one same field, while the fields corresponding to the tag are put appropriately in column A, B, C, etc.

(Just to illustrate:

row 1: 001 245 500|    [blank]      |  [blank]

row 2: XXXXXXXX   | YYYYY | ZZZZZZZZZZ

)

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open a .mrc file and export to a .csv file without the issue you're describing using a free tool called [C# MARC Editor](https://csharpmarc.net/).